# In physics we know that : $\text{instantaneous power}:=\dfrac{dw}{dt} $

Tags: calculus

In physics we know that :

$$\text{instantaneous power}:=\dfrac{dw}{dt} $$

And :

$$\text{average power}:=\dfrac{w}{t} $$

Let : $\text{instantaneous power}:=\dfrac{dw}{dt}=c:=\text{constant} $

Then  they say that :

$${dw}=c dt \to \int dw =\int c dt \to w=ct \to c=\dfrac{w}{t}:=\text{instantaneous power}$$

---

Now I want to know that Why we are allowed :

$$\dfrac{dw}{dt}=c\to dw= c dt $$

Comment: Integrate both sides with respect to $dt$, you will get,

$$\int\frac{dw}{dt}dt = \int cdt \implies \int dw = \int cdt$$

Answer (score 0):

Think about what the derivative is: it is the *rate* at which a function $y$ changes with respect to some variable $x$. So if you *assume* that the derivative $dw/dt$ is constant, then the rate at which the function $w$ changes is constant with respect to time.

It may not make concrete sense right now, but consider the example $y=2x$. Graphically, $y=2x$ is a straight line with no variation whatsoever. We get that $dy/dx = 2$ (a constant).

But also, the average rate of change (i.e. the slope) of $y=2x$ between any two points on the line is $m=2$.

Therefore, the average rate of change and the instantaneous rate of change are the same. Thus, in your example, you are assuming that the instantaneous rate of change is constant. This results in your work function $w$ just being a straight line. (your mistake is likely that you are thinking that the derivative yields a number, i.e. a constant, but in reality it yields a **particular** number at a **particular** value $t$, which could be different at many different $t$).